# Creating new blog on multisite programatically without hacks?

Tags: functions, multisite, domain

I'm attempting to create a new blog ( on localhost testing ) and I can't seem to find a straightforward way to do it. It appears this is not fully supported yet, but I want to make sure.

This is what I have:

```
wpmu_create_user( 'new_user', 'somepass', 'someone@url.com' );
global $user_id, $current_site;

wpmu_create_blog( $current_site->domain, 'test-1', 'This is a test...', $user_id , array( 'public' => 1 ), $current_site->id );
```

Yet when I look at the site created in the admin area, the link is to some butchered version of the url like httplocalhostwpinstallthenewsite

Can't figure it out :D

Of course the web is presently filled with all sorts of workarounds (I know this comes with wp-multisite territory) but I'm just double checking that there is not a supported way to pragmatically  create a blog without hacks.

Comment: WordPress itself uses the function when you create a site via the dashboard, so it certainly works. Immediately I see that your path is invalid, it should contain slashes if it's a subdirectory install - `/test-1/`. I don't have a multisite install to test, but a good starting point would be to grep `wpmu_create_blog` in source and see how it's used.

Comment: I'll double check this. It might be that I'm a little confused on the first two arguments the function takes then.

Comment: Be careful about the kind of network you have (subfolders or subdomains). [Codex page for wpmu_create_blog](https://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/wpmu_create_blog) says that: _"On subdirectory installs, $domain is the same as the main site's domain, and the path is the subdirectory name (eg 'example.com' and '/blog1/'). On subdomain installs, $domain is the new subdomain + root domain (eg 'blog1.example.com'), and $path is '/'."_